# Is it possible to include Outlook web AddIn into VSTO AddIn?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm new to development in Microsoft Office AddIns.
I created one Outlook Web AddIn with javascript/html/css.
Is it possible to create one Outlook VSTO AddIn, with a button for example, that opens the Web AddIn?

Comment: The comments below are right. You cannot do it because we currently don't support behavior like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. `OfficeJS` or `VSTO` (nor the Outlook extensibility model) doesn't provide any API for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. The best you can do is figure out from a VSTO addin if a particular JS addin is installed; but you cannot do anything with it.